# AWS master account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want a aws master account, where i can manage other aws accounts/iam users. Is this achievable? I tried with AWS Organizations, but it does not applies for IAM users(Only account level). Please help

Comment: Any AWS account that is not already a member account within an AWS Organization can become a main account for AWS Organizations. Do you have root credentials for the account?

Comment: Yes i have root account credentials, but in AWS organizations, the policies apply on account level.
FYI, I have a master account and two other accounts - one is dev and other one is prod. Under dev and prod i have multiple IAM users. the requirement is - dev and prod accounts must be connected to master account and by logging into master account i should be able to attach different policies for these IAM Users. Ploicies are different for each IAM users.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom role in any account that you have, and the use aws-api to assume this role with an script.

For example, you create the role **custom_role** in everyaccount that you own.

Then you use aws sdk or cli to assume role

- Configure role in credentials profile

> [profile custom_role]
>
> role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/custom_role
>
> source_profile = default

- Use aws api to create user in the other account

> aws iam create-user --user-name user_test --profile custom_role

You could do the same thing through aws sdk (like boto3 in python). If you want to manage all accounts, you could develop some script that automate that work.